# Char "Expression Must Have A Class Type"

Tags: c++, arrays, char, constants, winhttp

I'm trying to convert `pszOutBuffer` which is created below into a `const char *` 
So to do this I'm attempting to use `sprintf` to create a `char` called `buffer` and then finally getting the `buffer`'s `c_str()`. But `buffer` is thowing the error "Expression must have a class type"

```
if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,  
    dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
    printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError( ) );
 else
    printf( "%s", pszOutBuffer );
    char buffer [4096];
    sprintf(buffer,"%s",pszOutBuffer);
    returnval = buffer.c_str();
```

Comment: What is `pszOutBuffer` originally?

Answer (score 3):

A couple issues. One, you're missing braces on your else, and two you're trying to use `c_str` member function on a native type (char array).

I'm unsure what you meant to do (probably use `std::string`, but that wouldn't work very well with `sprintf`) but if you wanted to use `std::string` then you should use `std::stringstream` to emulate what `sprintf` is doing or just construct it with one of its constructors.